# Pass a Struct to a function and create an instance of that struct inside the function

Tags: swift, function, generics, struct

I want to make a function that accepts a Struct Type and inside that function, I want to return an instance of the created Struct.

For example:

```
struct Person {
  var name: String
  func greet() {
    print("Hi person \(self.name)")
  }
}

struct Animal {
  var name: String
  func greet() {
    print("Hi animal \(self.name)")
  }
}

// T is the stuct type, so I can pass either Person or Animal.
// name is the name string.
func greet<T>(_ a: T, name: String) {
  let thingToGreet: a = a(name: name)
  thingToGreet.greet()
}

// Pass the struct type and a string.
greet(Person, name: "Johny")
```

Is this even possible?
In application, I want to make a function that accepts a URL, a struct type then on completion I want to return the struct created based on the data task request.

Comment: I am confused... what is `a` and what his `T`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a protocol to explain to the compiler that A) these types have a `.name`, B) they have a `.greet()` function, and, finally, C) that they can be initialised with just `name`. In your `greet()` global function, you then refer to the protocol. The last wrinkles are that you pass in the type, and that you call the `init(name:)` explicitly...

```
protocol HasName {
    var name: String { get set }
    func greet()
    init(name: String)
}

struct Person: HasName {
    var name: String
    func greet() {
        print("Hi person \(self.name)")
    }
}

struct Animal: HasName {
    var name: String
    func greet() {
        print("Hi animal \(self.name)")
    }
}

// ** We demand T follows the protocol, 
// ** & declare A is a type that follows the protocol, not an instance
func greet<T: HasName>(_ A: T.Type, name: String) { 
    let thingToGreet = A.init(name: name) // ** A(name: ) doesn't work
    thingToGreet.greet()
}

// Pass the struct type and a string.
greet(Person.self, name: "Johny") // ** .self returns the type
```

Comment: Thanks. The protocol was the key and now I have more understanding of generics, protocols and structs.